# Visual Studio Items.Add (ComboBox) Not Working

Tags: c#, if-statement, combobox

I'm new to C# and Visual Studio, my teacher gave us a practice about adding list in combo box using the if else statement like the codes below. When I was working in my combo box, there's a time that the items that I wanted to add in the combo box does not appear and it's only empty.

```
private void Object()

if (comboBox1.Text == "Sample1" && comboBox2.Text == "Sample2" && comboBox3.Text == "Sample3")

{
  comboBox1.Items.Clear();
  comboBox1.Items.Add("Example 1")
  comboBox1.Items.Add("Example 2")
  comboBox1.Items.Add("Example 3")
  comboBox1.Items.Add("Example 4")
  comboBox1.Items.Add("Example 5")
}
```

This is my code for that part. It doesn't have an error but the code doesn't work. I tried my best to find where my wrong is but I couldn't find it. I'm wondering if it's a bug or I'm doing something wrong. Any suggestions and recommendations are highly appreciated :>.

I tried debugging but nothing happens. I'm just expecting to know what wrong I did in the codes and fully understand that part.

Comment: To start: is this method `Object()` called at all?

Comment: yes, it was also in the example that my teacher gave and it work perfectly fine there

Comment: So then take the opportunity to start learning how to use the debugger: put a brakpoint on the first line of the method, and when hit, inspect the values of the Text properties you use in the condition and step through your code.